# Strangest error on live Site, random massive circle appears with Safari and IE

Tags: jquery, html

This is on a live site so i hope to find a fix pretty quickly

I am completely stumped on this, a random gigantic circle with border only is appearing on my page when you click on the get a quote button, this loads a form via ajax, and then calls show on it, but on both ie and safari(a client noticed it on mac, i tested with IE and found it also) a gigantic massive circle appears when the content loads, i dont believe its a css issue and i tried inspecting the element but nothings there

the website is:
http://motionvideos.tv/
(click the banner (imagemap, the get a quote section))

Any help, advice or comments will be greatly appreciated, I have not seen something like this before =/

Comment: any specific versions of IE/Safari. Apart from inspecting the element, what else have you tried?

Comment: truthfully not much, i realized that this is not something i have any idea about, i tried it on both ie9 and ie8, on which it occurs on both but appears on disappears when either the content of that div is shown then hidden, (on each showing) as well as each time i press f12 to load the tools, this site does not use css3 and other then that i dont even have a clue how to make a circle let alone what makes one without a container or why this occurs =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got an image map with your logo link.

Inside, you have one of the areas specified as a 'circle', when I believe you meant 'rect'.

```
<area shape="circle" coords="650,57,1000,115" href="JavaScript:void(0);" alt="Get A Quote" title="Get A Quote" onclick="loadForm()">
```

change to

```
<area shape="rect" coords="650,57,1000,115" href="JavaScript:void(0);" alt="Get A Quote" title="Get A Quote" onclick="loadForm()">
```

The circle you were/are seeing, seems to be the "focus" state of the map `area`.

Goodluck.

Comment: lifesaver, must of been alseep when i typed that, thankyou so much for finding that =]